# StackNavigation how to know from which screen I navigated from?

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm currently using a StackNavigator in my react native app.

I have two screens which both will navigate to the same screen `LoginScreen`. However, depending on which screen I came from, I'd like to go to different screens.

e.g:

> ScreenA -> LoginScreen -> ScreenC
>
> ScreenB -> LoginScreen -> ScreenD

As such in the LoginScreen I need to know which screen I've come from so that I know whether to go to screen C or D.

But the goBack function on the this.props.navigation is just a function that takes you back to the last screen. It doesn't give you the ID of the screen or some way of determining where you came from.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login Screen would expect a flag, call it `IsScreenA`, this variable will come from Screen A and B as `true` or`false` respectively. Then, in Login Screen, navigate based on that flag:

```
if(this.props.IsScreenA)
   this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenC")
else
   this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenD")
```

Now for the go back, use [**my answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738324/5890227) along with the above logic. You would call LoginScreen, and then based on whatever screen, you pass a different `goBack()`.

Edit:

To pass a parameter, you do something like this:

From Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen", {IsScreenA: true});
```

From Screen B:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen", {IsScreenA: false});
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought it would be something like this. How do you add a flag when you navigate? Something like, this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen', true); ?

Comment: Khalil you sir are a boss! Cheers!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Good luck :)